# I want to login in morningstar with selenium in python

Tags: python, selenium, authentication, selenium-webdriver

when i try to login in morningstar this happens -> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

This is my code:

```py
import random
from time import sleep
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.morningstar.es/es/funds/snapshot/snapshot.aspx?id=F00000XDCO')
boton_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="individualinvestor"]/span[1]')
boton_1.click()
sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 3.0))
boton_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="_evidon-accept-button"]')
boton_2.click()
sleep(random.uniform(4.0, 8.0))
entrar = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="signInLabel"]').click()
sleep(random.uniform(1.0, 3.0))
email = driver.find_elements_by_id('txtUsername').send_keys("email")
```

Answer (score 1):

`driver.find_elements_by_id('txtUsername')` returns a list of web elements.
You can not send text to a list of web elements.
You can only send text to a specific web element.
So you have to use `driver.find_element_by_id('txtUsername').send_keys("email")`
Or `list = driver.find_elements_by_id('txtUsername')` and then `list[0].send_keys("email")`

In this case it looks like you just made a mistake, you just should use `email = driver.find_element_by_id('txtUsername').send_keys("email")` here

Answer (score 0):

You are using `find_elements_by` this is wrong you should be using `find_element_by`

`find_elements_by` returns a list and you cant send an email to a list so you should use `find_element_by`

so just remove the s from `find_elements_by`

Comment: I wrote that 3 minutes before :)

Comment: i didnt see yours when i post it the page was empty of :)

Comment: Sure, I just see this like a joke. Very simple mistake of Socrame